# Jest, data in one test bleeding to another

Tags: jestjs

I have been facing this issue with jest, where the data i set in one test is creeping into another test and causing it to fail.

Let me try to show some code

`spec.ts`

```
const MOCK_PRODUCT = require('../dummydata/dummydata.json');

describe('function 1', () => {
  test('something', () => {
    const productData = MOCK_PRODUCT;
    expect(...) // works fine
  });

  test('something else', () => {
    const productData = MOCK_PRODUCT;
    productData.someField.push({...})
    expect(...) // works fine
  });
});

describe('function 2', () => {
  test('something more', () => {
    const productData = MOCK_PRODUCT;
    expect(...) // fails
  });
});
```

My test file goes like this. There is a describe block for each function and multiple tests inside the describe block.

What i observe is that, when i changed the productData in second test as you see above, the changed data is available in all the tests in the next describe block, causing them to fail.

Am i doing something wrong? is something missing?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that is by design. The script is just run from top to bottom. `beforeAll`, `beforeEach`, `afterEach` and `afterAll` functions could help you to factor out some code from your test methods.

You can also use the `cloneDeep` function from `lodash` to make an completely independent copy of the test data before each test runs.

```js
const MOCK_PRODUCT = require('../dummydata/dummydata.json');
const _ = require('lodash'),
let productData = undefined;
beforeEach(() => {
  productData = _.cloneDeep(MOCK_PRODUCT);
})

describe('function 1', () => {
  test('something', () => {
    expect(...) // works fine
  });

  test('something else', () => {
    productData.someField.push({...})
    expect(...) // works fine
  });
});

describe('function 2', () => {
  test('something more', () => {
    expect(...) // fails
  });
});
```

Comment: Tried both and it behaves the same. For some reason it is not clearing the previously set field

Comment: Okay, then it seems you need the big boy, lodash deepclone, which creates you a brand new copy of the required test data. I will update the answer accordingly, I did not know require caches the loaded object.

Comment: @aneeshere Could I help you with this solution?

Comment: I tried once but it did not work. I could not check more on it due to other commitments.

Answer (score 0):

It seems `MOCK_PRODUCT` is a object, then when you set `const productData = MOCK_PRODUCT;`, the `productData` is a referent to `MOCK_PRODUCT`. This means if you update `producData` content, `MOCK_PRODUCT` content also be updated.

In the previous test, you update `productData` object, then the next test will not working as your expected.

A simple way to avoid it is to stop using referent way, just clone to a new object for every test.

```
const productData = {...MOCK_PRODUCT};
```

My recommendation, define `productData` variable at the top level, assign cloned `MOCK_PRODUCT` for it in `beforeEach`. Then use `productData` in each test.

Comment: Do you mean, it is a classic case of object reference being updated? and each test actually picks from this reference?

Comment: @aneeshere yes, `MOCK_PRODUCT ` defined as a global variable, and I guess it is an object.

Comment: yes it is an object. I had done some sort of cloning before, but let me just do it again. I can do the cloning in beforeEach right? Or should i do it in each test? Or is it both essentially the same?

Comment: Yes, you can do it in breforeEach block.

Comment: `productData.someField.push({...})` suggests that someField is an array. The spread operator does a shallow copy, so if you add new properties to the copy or change their scalar values, the origial will remain intact. But you will push to the original someField array if you do not use deep clone.